# How to get enemyTransform.position from OnTriggerEnter()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oop

How can I obtain the `enemyTransform.position` when calling the Teleport() function?

The `enemyTransform` is saved upon collision with the enemy object, and the teleport button can be pressed at any time after `OnTriggerEnter`

Since the enemy can move, I want the teleportation to occur at the current position of the enemy.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using ThrowOrbNamespace;

public class orbLogic : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ThrowOrbNamespace.ThrowOrb throwOrb;

    public Button teleportButton;

    public CharacterController characterController;

    private Transform enemyTransform;

    void Start()
    {
        teleportButton.interactable = false;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {    
            enemyTransform = other.transform;

            throwOrb.StopAll();

            Destroy(gameObject);

            teleportButton.interactable = true;

            Debug.Log(enemyTransform.position); //enemyTransform != null
        }
    }

    public void Teleport()
    {
        Debug.Log(enemyTransform.position); //enemyTransform == null
        if (enemyTransform != null)
        {
            characterController.enabled = false;
            characterController.transform.position = enemyTransform.position;
            characterController.enabled = true;

            teleportButton.interactable = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well you're destroying whatever this code is on.. is this your character?

Comment: @BugFinder No, it's a sphere thrown by the character, it should disappear upon hitting the enemy

Comment: @BugFinder Even if I don't delete it, the script still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : getting the current position of Enemytransform , instead saving it on trigger enter

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using ThrowOrbNamespace;

public class orbLogic : MonoBehaviour
{        
    public ThrowOrbNamespace.ThrowOrb throwOrb;    
    public Button teleportButton;    
    public CharacterController characterController;    
    [SerializeField] private Transform enemyTransform;          

    void Start()
    {           
         teleportButton.interactable = false;       
    }
 
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {            
         if (other.CompareTag("Enemy"))
         {                   
         // MAKE THE BUTTON INTERACTABLE
            throwOrb.StopAll();    
            Destroy(gameObject);    
            teleportButton.interactable = true;
        }
    }

    public void Teleport()
    {                     
            characterController.enabled = false;
            characterController.transform.position = enemyTransform.position; // GET THE RUNTIME position of enemy
            characterController.enabled = true;    
            teleportButton.interactable = false;            
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this doing different from what OP already had except that now you have to reference the `enemyTransform` via the inspector instead of taking the object you hit in `OnTriggerEnter` which is the desired effect ...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
Destroy(gameObject);
```

which destroys this object right away you could try and rather only hide it

```
gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

and then only `Destroy` it within the `Teleport` method.

Comment: I'm getting an error in line "Debug.Log(enemyTransform.position);" because the enemy's transform is not being passed to Teleport() from OnTriggerEnter(). I can't assign the enemy's transform in advance since there are many of them on the map.